# Google API Core Library and Python version requirements

Tags: python, google-api

I'm using pipenv on a project with Python 3.6.4 and when installing dependencies I receive this error:

`Could not find a version that matches futures>=3.2.0
Tried: 0.2.python3, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.6, 2.2.0, 2.2.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.5, 3.1.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.1`

After running `pipenv lock -v` I can see that `google-api-core` is a secondary dependency and it requires the following:

`google-api-core==0.1.4    requires futures>=3.2.0; python_version < "3.2", google-auth<2.0.0dev,>=0.4.0, googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.5.3, protobuf>=3.0.0, pytz, requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0, setuptools>=34.0.0, six>=1.10.0`

Does this mean that `google-api-core` requires the outdated Python 3.2?